# Insert from Chrome console does not work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, meteor

I'm new to Meteor.js. I am reading [Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/) and I'm stuck at this point:

```
Posts.insert({ title: 'Meteor Docs', author: 'Tom Coleman', url: 'http://docs.meteor.com'});
```

I'm running this statement on Chrome console, and Chrome replies with the `object-id`, but the screen does not change. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

When you do Posts.find().count(); in the browser console, what do you get? If you get 0, then might have named your collections differently.

Sharing some code always helps people to better answer your question.